Help with computations of first return time in an integrable system
I have example of an integrable system $(J,H):M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ where $J$ generates an $S^1$-action for which I'm trying to compute the action-angle coordinates. I have done all the steps but in the end my result is wrong since I do not straight lines in the boundary of my domain , which should happen since I'm trying to obtain action-angle coordinates. Therefore I wanted to check if my computation of first return time is actually correct. The first return time of $(j,h)$ is defined as the time it takes for the orbit $\phi^{t}_{H}(p_{j,h})$  to intersect the orbit $\phi^{t}_{J}(p_{j,h})$, where $p_{j,h}$ is a point such that $(J,H)(p_{j,h})=(j,h)$, where this is a regular value. Working in the reduced space $J^{-1}(j)/S^1$ this equals the period of reduced motion of $X_{H}$.
I have found that the reduced space $J^{-1}(j)/S^1$ is the with the semi-algebraic variety given by
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
    \pi_5^2+\pi_6^2=\pi_1^2\pi_3\pi_4 \\
    \pi_1+2j+2\pi_3=6\\
    \pi_3+\pi_4=2
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $\pi_i, i=1,...,6$ are the following polynomials in $\mathbb{R}^8$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
    \pi_1:=x_1^2+y_1^2\\
    \pi_2:=x_2^2+y_2^2\\
    \pi_3:=x_3^2+y_3^2\\
    \pi_4:=x_4^2+y_4^2\\
    \pi_5:=\Re(\overline{z_1}^2z_3\overline{z_4})\\
    \pi_6:=\Im(\overline{z_1}^2z_3\overline{z_4})\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $z_j=x_j+iy_j$. In particular we have that $H=\pi_5$.
A simple computation gives that
\begin{equation}
    \dot{\pi_3}=\{\pi_3,\pi_5\}=-2\pi_6.
\end{equation}
Using these results we can now compute the first return time $T(j,h)$. We have
\begin{align}
T(j,h)=\int_{0}^{T(j,h)}dt=2\int_{\pi_3^{-}}^{\pi_3^{+}}\frac{d\pi_3}{\dot{\pi_3}}=\int_{\pi_3^{-}}^{\pi_3^{+}}\frac{d\pi_3}{\sqrt{4(3-\pi_3-j)^2\pi_3(2-\pi_3)-h^2}}
\end{align}
where $\pi_3^{\pm}$ are the real roots of $S_{j,h}:=4(3-\pi_3-j)^2\pi_3(2-\pi_3)-h^2$.
Since I am fairly new to actually computing action-angle coordinates I wanna make sure what I am doing makes sense, so any insight is appreciated. Thanks in advance.
